# Magento2: How to remove footer and header for the second store created?

Tags: magento2, footer, stores, headerlink

I have created two stores in Magento2.
One is main website and the second one is retailer site.
I need to remove the footer section and the navigation bar for my retailer site.
I also need to remove the favorites section from the header only for my retailer site.

Please anyone guide me on this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way to can remove the block from the layout.

Create layout unique handle fro each store like `store_en` , `store_retailer`, where to assume that the `retailer` is the store code of your retailer store & `en is default store code.

Add [**custom layout handle**](https://belvg.com/blog/module-layout-handles-in-magento-2.html) using on `layout_load_before`.

## Observer code

```
 <?php
namespace StackExchange\Magento\Observer\Frontend;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

        $handlecode ='store_'.strtolower($this->storeManager->getStore()->getCode());
        $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle($handlecode);
        return $this;
    }

}


        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {

               $layout = $observer->getLayout();
           $handlecode = 'store_'. strtolower($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode());
               $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle($handlecode);

           return $this;
        }
    }
```

After adding this observer, you need to do Cache flush/Di compile.

Now. if you need to create a handler file at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{Module Name}/view/frontend/layout/store_{retailerSITEStoreCode}.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi Amit after adding your code I am getting this error Warning: Uncaught Exception: Warning: require(/var/www/html/magento2_dev/pub/errors/report.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/

Comment: Could you please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: Still the same error I am receiving.

Comment: Please check your files/folder permission...

Comment: Thanks Amit, It is working perfectly fine.. Ur really a genius.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a `child theme` for your retailer site and remove elements accordingly.

Comment: Can you share me some examples, how to create a child theme

Comment: I have already created a child theme for my main website.